# how to disable reload option in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have developed on plugin by using google chrome extension API.

By using "Load unpacked extension" button I can install the my plugin in to chrome browser,

I will get 3 option in the "Reload", "Disable" and "Uninstall".

How can I disable Reload option for my extension. I am attaching the image for reference

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cant.

Although theoretically you could write a NPAPI plugin that would do this I recommend against it.